# Custom Bokeh Circle icons / images

Tags: python, bokeh

I want custom icons for my circles from icon.png. Could not find any property of Circle to change it.

I want each circle to be an image instead of a filled.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.models import Circle, ColumnDataSource, Grid, LinearAxis, Plot

N = 9
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, N)
y = x**2
sizes = np.linspace(10, 20, N)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x, y=y, sizes=sizes))

plot = Plot(
    title=None, plot_width=300, plot_height=300,
    min_border=0, toolbar_location=None)

glyph = Circle(x="x", y="y", size="sizes", line_color="#3288bd", fill_color="white", line_width=3)
plot.add_glyph(source, glyph)

xaxis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(xaxis, 'below')

yaxis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(yaxis, 'left')

plot.add_layout(Grid(dimension=0, ticker=xaxis.ticker))
plot.add_layout(Grid(dimension=1, ticker=yaxis.ticker))

curdoc().add_root(plot)

show(plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option at present (version 2.4.2) is to use [`ImageURL`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/image_url.html?highlight=imageurl) to display images at the specified coordinates.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    url = [...],
    x1  = np.linspace(  0, 150, N),
    y1  = np.linspace(  0, 150, N),
))

im = ImageURL(url="url", x="x1", y="y1", w=10, h=10, anchor="center")
plot.add_glyph(source, im)
```

Note that the URLs for the images must be accessible to any viewer of the plot.

Future releases will support `anchor` property for `ImageRGBA` so that will become an option as well.